# Moving some files with the same extension in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

First excuse, since I am not an English native and even English language is not my second language.
I want to move some files with .txt extension from one folder eg F:\From to another eg. F:\To. using VB.net
I don't want to move all files, but some of them e.g. 20 or 30 and leave others at the destination folder (F:\To).
For example, 120 text files are in the source folder (F:\From ) can I move half of them to the destination folder (F:\To), and leave other half at the source folder, that is, each of the two folders (the source and the destination) should have the same number of files.
Actually, the number of files in the destination folder may change, but I want to move only some of them, not all of them.
Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Mark Hurd, you helped me well. I tried the following code and it works:

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim sourceDir = "F:\From"
    Dim destinationDir = "F:\To"

    ' get the filenames of txt files
    Dim SourceFiles = From f In Directory.GetFiles(sourceDir, "*.txt")
    Dim DestinationFiles = From f In Directory.GetFiles(destinationDir, "*.txt")

    'Calculate the difference in files between the two folders, and move files if the files
    'in source folder are more than the files of the destination folder
    Dim s As Integer
    s = SourceFiles.Count - DestinationFiles.Count

    'Find the remainder 
    Dim a = s Mod 2

    'If the remainder is zero, then divide the 
    If a = 0 Then
        Dim files = From f In Directory.GetFiles(sourceDir, "*.txt").Take(s / 2)

        If Not Directory.Exists(destinationDir) Then
            Directory.CreateDirectory(destinationDir)
        End If

        Dim n As Integer = 0
        For Each f In files

            File.Move(f, Path.Combine(destinationDir, Path.GetFileName(f)))
        Next
    Else
        Dim files = From f In Directory.GetFiles(sourceDir, "*.txt").Take((s + 1) / 2)
        If Not Directory.Exists(destinationDir) Then
            Directory.CreateDirectory(destinationDir)
        End If

        Dim n As Integer = 0
        For Each f In files

            File.Move(f, Path.Combine(destinationDir, Path.GetFileName(f)))
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't say which version of VB.NET. With recent versions (.NET Framework 4.0) you can do something like:

```
Dim filesToMove = From f In New DirectoryInfo("F:\From").EnumerateFiles("*.txt") _
         Where <insert condition selecting the files to move>

For Each f In filesToMove
    f.MoveTo("F:\To")
Next
```

With older frameworks you need to use `.GetFiles` instead, which, for this purpose, just has different performance characteristics, and if you're using an old VB.NET without LINQ you'd need something like:

```
For Each f In New DirectoryInfo("F:\From").GetFiles("*.txt")
  If Not <condition selecting files> Then _
    Continue For

  f.MoveTo("F:\To")
Next
```

Comment: Thank you very much Mark Hurd. You answer is brief and to the point. I will change the .net frame to 4.0. and I will try to use this code and add to the condition to select files. Thank you again.

Comment: Ok, Mark, I used your code and it works fine, but still I could not insert the condition, I mean there an error in the where-clause syntax. Can you please help me again. Thank You Very Much

Comment: You have not mentioned what the condition is for moving. Either update your question or if it is complex you may want to ask a new question.